# PostgreSQL : Get first and last inserted record for each ID column

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table with two columns.

**Table**:

```
create table tbl1
(
    p_id int,
    p_price int
);
```

**Insertion**:

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 values(1,100);
INSERT INTO tbl1 values(1,50);  
INSERT INTO tbl1 values(1,20);

INSERT INTO tbl1 values(2,10);  
INSERT INTO tbl1 values(2,20);

INSERT INTO tbl1 values(3,22);  
INSERT INTO tbl1 values(3,89);  
INSERT INTO tbl1 values(3,500);
```

Query: Following query gives me the row number of each row.

```
SELECT p_id,p_price,row_number() over(partition by p_id order by p_id) rn
from tbl1
```

I want to get only first and last inserted record for each product id (p_id).

**Expected Result**:

```
p_id    p_price    
-----------------
1   100
1   20
2   10  
2   20
3   22
3   500
```

Comment: There is no "first" and "last" inserted record in Postgres or most flavors of SQL.  You will need to define some order here.

Comment: There is no such thing as "first" or "last" inserted row. And the `order by` you are using will not give you what you want as all values you sort by are the same - and thus the database is free to return those rows in any order it wants

Comment: Try having another column as `createdDate` which logs the datetime the record inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using subquery:

```
SELECT p_id, p_price, rn from (
  SELECT *, last_value(rn) over(partition by p_id) as last  from (
    SELECT p_id,p_price,row_number() over(partition by p_id order by p_id) rn
    FROM tbl1
  ) s1
) s2 where rn=1 or rn=last;
```

So at inner select you get the row number by partition, one level up you get the last row numbers (first is always 1).
Then the top level can do the filter.

Comment: this is not first and last inserted. the result will change over time for same `p_id`

Comment: @VaoTsun yes, you are right, without storing sequence or date of insert it will not surely give correctly the first and last inserted rows. If it is needed, the table can be extended and the query modified to do that. Eventually ID is not a PK in the example. The PK could contain e.g. the insertion time.